# Embeded responsive design

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

So I have a "mobile web app" which I am embeding it in an iframe.. on a website, but the problem is that on the website..it looks too small, I think because It's not picking up the

`<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />`

Is there a solution to show the same font sizes and stuff on the iframe as well?

Comment: You will need to style the iframe as well. This has a good answer to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113507/append-meta-tag-to-the-head-of-the-main-document-from-iframe

Comment: Some HTML would also be useful if possible :)